# Is there a way to mark lines in Atmel Studio's Memory Window

Tags: visual-studio, memory, microcontroller, atmelstudio

I have to use Atmel Studio for a project and I'm using
the memory window very often, to look on specific data Segments of the microcontroller.

Unfortunately It's very hard to keep track of specific lines in this window, looking like this:

[image]

especially switching between multiple locations. Is there a way to mark specific lines, maybe with a background color, or anything like that? I couldn't find a feature like that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I can try to give you my decision. When you move the cursor over a segment of memory, a cell with the segment value pops up. If you click on the pin button, you fix the cell, and you will can add your comments to the cell.
P.S.: Sorry for my English.
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpREW.png)

You can also Hexplorer. This is specifical comfortable .hex editor.